# The two functions were compared to the bracket. IIFE execution. Results NaN

Tags: nan, iife

The function of the numeric return and the function of the undefined return in bracket were compared and then executed with IIFE. The result is NaN. What happened?

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
console.log(
    (
        new Point(5, 8).sum || (() => undefined)
    )() // IIFE : undefined
);

// sum() added
Point.prototype.sum = function () {
    return this.x + this.y;
}

console.log(
    (new Point(5, 8).sum)() 
    // 13
);

console.log(
    // typeof : number
    (
        new Point(5, 8).sum || (() => undefined)

    )()//! IIFE : NaN. ???? WH~~~Y????
);
```

At the last console.log, the bare mental collapsed.
Let me know why....:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called in that context, `this` is not what you expect it to be; it's coming from the surrounding context because the `sum` function is unbound.

This means that your function body ends up evaluating `undefined + undefined`, which is `NaN`.

A simplified example of this problem can be seen with:

```js
let p = new Point(5, 8)
let f1 = p.sum
f1() //-> NaN
```

Instead, you can manually pass in a parameter to be `this`:

```js
f1.call(p) //-> 13
```

Or you can explicitly bind that function to a specific `this`:

```js
let f2 = Point.prototype.sum.bind(new Point(5, 8))
f2() //-> 13
```

Comment: awesome!
The trap I made, I fell for it.
You gave me a wise answer to my mistake.
Thank you for your kind reply.